# Actionbar wont show in all activities

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779340/see-action-bar-across-all-activities-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765985/reusing-action-bar-in-all-activities-of-application) question to create a BaseActivity with an action bar compat (with v7 library), that will be extended by other activities.

The action bar is working perfectly when i set the default activity as "BaseActivity", however the action bar is never shown when i extended it to another activity, lets say HomeActivity.

The `onCreate` code in BaseActivity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

    }
```

The `onCreateOptionsMenu` :

```
@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And this is the HomeActivity, note that i commented the `onCreateOptionsMenu` because i already have it in the BaseActivity :

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        //getSupportActionBar().show();
    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }*/

}
```

This is my manifest :

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_whats_hot"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.test.testlivescore.BaseActivity"
            android:label="base" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.test.testlivescore.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: My best guess is incorrect theme setting in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @sgarman i have included my manifest in the question, Thanks

Comment: You do not need to use setContentView() in BaseActivity. And do not launch this activity it's only works as super class of other activities. And declare it as `abstract` class.

Comment: @KetanAhir i need to use the setContentView() in base because the xml contains a listview for my navigation drawer.I dont have any intent-filter in the baseactivity, so it should'nt be launched

Comment: why don't you use another activity for that which extends BaseActivity ?

Comment: @KetanAhir sorry, what do you mean? I used HomeActivity that extends BaseActivity

Comment: use one more activity for `listview for my navigation drawer` which extends BaseActivity.

Comment: @KetanAhir but i also need the navigation drawer for all of the activity..is it possible?

Comment: May be possible if create Drawar in java code(not sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is rather simple but takes time to figure out the root cause.

When you use `supportActionBar` methods, you have to extend `ActionBarActivity`. This activity is included in the `support library`.

[ActionBarActivity docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)

So your code becomes:

```
public class BaseActiivity extends ActionBarActivity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // actionbar Code
    }

}

public class MainActivity extends BaseAcivity{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: This might make sense.. :)